# What is the use of lucene index files in DBPedia-Spotlight..?

Tags: lucene, dbpedia, named-entity-recognition, lingpipe

I am trying to find named entities in a given text.  For that, I have tried using DBPedia spotlight service.

1. I am able to get a response out of that. However, the DBPedia dataset is limited, so I tried replacing their spotter.dict file with my own dictionary. My dictionary contains entities per line:

   Sachin Tendulkar###PERSON

   Barack Obama ###PERSON

   .... etc
2. Then I parse this file and build an `ExactDictionaryChunker` object.
3. Now I am able to get the entities and their types (after modification of dbpedia code).

My Question is: DBPedia spotlight is using Lucene Index files.  I really don't understand for what purpose they are using these files?

Can we do it without using Index files? Whats the significance of the index files?

Comment: Looks like there is some explanation of how Lucene is used in their [Github wiki](https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/Lucene---Architecture)

Comment: Thanks for your response.. But here they not at all discussed about lucene index. It's too abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene was used in the earlier implementation of DBpedia Spotlight to store a model of each entity in our KB. This model is used to give us a relatedness measure between the context (extracted from your input text) and the entity. More concretely, each entity is represented by a vector `{t1: score1, t2: score2, ... }`. At runtime we model your input text as a vector in the same dimensions and measure the cosine between input vector and entity vectors. In your case, you would have to add a vector for Sachin Tendulkar to the space (add a document to the Lucene index) in case it is not already there. The latest implementation, though, has moved away from Lucene to an in-house in-memory context store. https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/Internationalization-(DB-backed-core)